# Get the id of parent listview in child listview checkbox change event

Tags: asp.net, listview

On  chkSubModuleView_CheckedChanged() event iwant to get the id of chkModule.Please tell me how to get the id or reference of parent checkbox on click of child checkbox in server side.How to distinguish between different modules .

```
enter code here

<asp:ListView ID="lvModule" runat="server">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table width="600px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"     
class="ListViewtable">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 10%;">
                                Modules
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"> 
</asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkModule" runat="server"   
CausesValidation="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                OnCheckedChanged="chkModule_CheckedChanged" > 
</asp:CheckBox><asp:HiddenField ID="hfEntityName"
                                    Value='<%# Eval("EntityName") %>' runat="server" />
                            <%# Eval("Title")%>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfID" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>'   
runat="server" />
                            <asp:Label ID="label" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 20px;">
                            <asp:ListView ID="lvSubModule" runat="server">
                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0"   
class="ListViewtableLayer2">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="width: 20%;">
                                                Sub Module
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="width: 20%;">
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSubModuleView"  
Checked="true" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"

OnCheckedChanged="chkSubModuleView_CheckedChanged" />
                                                View
                                            </th>

                                        </tr>
                                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder"   
runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    </table>
                                </LayoutTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <%# Eval("Title")%>
                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfMenuID" Value='<%#  
Eval("MenuID") %>' runat="server" />
                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfName" Value='<%#   
Eval("HeaderID") %>' runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRead" runat="server"  
AutoPostBack="true" Checked="true" CausesValidation="false"

OnCheckedChanged="chkRead_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your checkbox property to

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSubModuleView"  
Checked="true" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  Key='<%# Eval("ID")%>'
OnCheckedChanged="chkSubModuleView_CheckedChanged" />
```

In your .cs

```
protected void chkSubModuleView_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
string yourID = chk.Attributes["Key"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: This code perfectly works for me ! Just Check your data-binding for your ListView . Is `ID` bind correctly ?

Comment: add `<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval ("ID") %>' runat="server" ID = "testing"></asp:Label>`in your list view  and see what will happen !

Comment: Through label how to get the value in server side.Can u please update by writing code.

Comment: label value is coming as null.As this checkbox is present in layout template.But it is coming in child item template. But i want in layout template